# Could interaction effects prevent GLMM's (lme4) from converging?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction, glmm

In the following analysis, I am exploring the association between health outcomes and a range of environmental and socioeconomic predictors. These data have been collected from 9 countries, over multiple time periods. My response variable is Poisson and I'm using 'Region' and 'community_ID' as random intercepts (I dropped 'year' as a random slope since it was near perfectly correlated with 'Region'). I'm also using Laplace approximation and the bobyqa optimizer. I have c.90k observations (households, using household size as an offset).

I'm including a 2-way interaction effect. My GLMM (lme4 ver. 1.1-13) converges without these interaction terms. However, as soon as I add them in I get the dreaded:

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00293116 (tol = 0.001, component 
1)
```

I've followed the very useful guidance on convergence warnings found in the lme4 package; checking singularity (not an issue), recomputing gradient and Hessian with numDeriv package (Richardson extrapolation): c.0.0005.

I've tried a range of optimizers using allFit (lme4), and bumping up the number of iterations - none of this resolves the issue. The coefficient of variation of parameter estimates is mean: 0.037, max: 0.17) so I'm keen to find out what the issue is.

I suspect the issue may be because for some regions (Region) and communities (community_ID) there is zero deforestation and perhaps this is leading to some kind of separation? (However, I removed all observations with zero deforestation and the issue persisted).

I've attached a sample of the code for reference, but this isn't big enough to replicate the error. Here are links to a simplified version of the [full dataset](http://jmp.sh/v/hPA76blX4cmL9Sq6Ojez) and [code & diagnostics](http://jmp.sh/v/v5C2m5fdbAT7rd06nkiM), but I can share this somewhere else if preferred? The model is a bit more complex (with about 6 more variables), but the full dataset in the link and the below code reproduces the error.

```
# sample code - why does my model not converge when using an interaction 
# effect
#DF
sample_df<- read.csv("sample_df.csv", header = T) # which can be found here: 
http://jmp.sh/v/hPA76blX4cmL9Sq6Ojez
# load lme4
library(lme4)

# sample model code 
# Region_1 and community as random intercepts 
# maxfun=1e8
# response_offset as offset
model1 <- glmer(response ~  var1 + var2  +  
scale(deforestation,scale=T,center=T) + scale(var3,scale=T,center=T) +             
scale(deforestation,scale=T,center=T)*scale(var3,scale=T,center=T) + 
scale(var4, scale = T, center = T) +var5 + var6 + scale(var7, scale = T, 
center = T) + var8 + var9 + var10 + (1 | Region) + (1| community_ID), 
family=poisson, offset = log(response_offset) , 
control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e8), optimizer = 
"bobyqa"),nAGQ = 1, data = sample_df) 

## sample of dataset - not sufficient to reproduce the error
sample_small <- structure(list(community_ID = structure(c(36L, 19L, 89L, 
22L, 
82L, 35L, 73L, 21L, 14L, 62L, 48L, 67L, 47L, 29L, 50L, 1L, 23L, 
15L, 78L, 75L, 54L, 52L, 2L, 76L, 18L, 71L, 33L, 40L, 13L, 51L, 
28L, 57L, 9L, 61L, 70L, 11L, 99L, 43L, 63L, 38L, 5L, 64L, 98L, 
6L, 44L, 97L, 45L, 4L, 42L, 80L, 58L, 34L, 77L, 79L, 27L, 68L, 
55L, 7L, 60L, 26L, 16L, 31L, 72L, 37L, 83L, 93L, 10L, 3L, 87L, 
20L, 85L, 17L, 25L, 86L, 69L, 88L, 66L, 74L, 94L, 12L, 81L, 65L, 
41L, 56L, 59L, 76L, 39L, 32L, 90L, 96L, 53L, 49L, 8L, 24L, 92L, 
84L, 95L, 46L, 30L, 91L), .Label = c("ID1024", "ID1076", "ID121", 
"ID1247", "ID129", "ID1317", "ID1540", "ID1564", "ID1618", "ID1622", 
"ID1656", "ID1672", "ID1721", "ID1831", "ID197", "ID2086", "ID2140", 
"ID2173", "ID2368", "ID2382", "ID2397", "ID2408", "ID2672", "ID2807", 
"ID2883", "ID2980", "ID3024", "ID3070", "ID3076", "ID3131", "ID317", 
"ID3178", "ID3359", "ID3441", "ID3570", "ID3666", "ID3670", "ID3703", 
"ID3984", "ID4165", "ID4169", "ID4310", "ID4679", "ID5024", "ID5157", 
"ID516", "ID5179", "ID52", "ID5220", "ID5281", "ID5329", "ID5406", 
"ID5416", "ID5426", "ID5784", "ID595", "ID6010", "ID6032", "ID6113", 
"ID6125", "ID6154", "ID6193", "ID620", "ID6256", "ID633", "ID6379", 
"ID6415", "ID6470", "ID6623", "ID6727", "ID6782", "ID6811", "ID6918", 
"ID720", "ID7211", "ID7258", "ID7483", "ID7532", "ID7598", "ID7629", 
"ID7640", "ID7673", "ID7682", "ID7732", "ID7770", "ID7817", "ID7941", 
"ID8030", "ID8043", "ID8237", "ID8351", "ID8398", "ID8470", "ID8532", 
"ID8894", "ID8982", "ID903", "ID9181", "ID9366"), class = "factor"), 
var1 = c("D", "D", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", 
"D", "A", "C", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "C", "D", "C", "D", 
"C", "D", "C", "A", "A", "D", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", "A", 
"A", "D", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "A", "D", "D", 
"C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "D", "C", "C", "C", 
"A", "A", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", "D", "A", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "A", "C", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "D", "C", 
"D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", "C", "C", "C", "D", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D"), var2 = c("D", "D", "B", "A", 
"B", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "D", "B", "B", "D", "B", "B", 
"B", "D", "D", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", 
"D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", 
"B", "D", "B", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "B", "A", "B", 
"D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "D", "B", "B", "D", "B", "B", "D", 
"A", "D", "B", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "D", "B", "D", "C"
), var3 = c(280.98687664042, 198.021739130435, 223.126373626374, 
250.886178861789, 164.8125, 154.229946524064, 228.932432432432, 
236.991978609626, 242.590163934426, 193.067934782609, 279.228494623656, 
289.819672131148, 235.349462365591, 176.127371273713, 273.013986013986, 
252.890710382514, 235.468834688347, 263.64247311828, 192.55795148248, 
277.326145552561, 247.773936170213, 269.536388140162, 233.283018867925, 
219.552845528455, 238.650406504065, 251.406593406593, 243.906914893617, 
271.983957219251, 181.067750677507, 216.33423180593, 182.770053475936, 
247.76902173913, 227.219839142091, 199.572207084469, 262.950769230769, 
252.601648351648, 109.408983451537, 268.202156334232, 277.55585106383, 
179.699731903485, 280.970744680851, 206.183288409703, 150.332541567696, 
201.097625329815, 260.80701754386, 273.059299191375, 256.634408602151, 
196.655263157895, 265.768392370572, 168.576923076923, 201.112637362637, 
237.638814016173, 273.888283378747, 239.621621621622, 187.210106382979, 
217.741239892183, 174.32972972973, 249.873278236915, 173.927223719677, 
286.260752688172, 247.257978723404, 281.596816976127, 284.693989071038, 
210.688172043011, 187.654794520548, 266.941333333333, 184.409214092141, 
283.09549071618, 182.908108108108, 226.668449197861, 147.795640326975, 
255.125340599455, 199.092391304348, 183.027397260274, 205.79674796748, 
221.597260273973, 258.233695652174, 281.632, 256.177111716621, 
252.918032786885, 154.303278688525, 284.19414893617, 260.640957446808, 
273.844919786096, 230.843406593407, 219.552845528455, 261.828877005348, 
164.723860589812, 236.059620596206, 138.143529411765, 285.161725067385, 
234.46949602122, 250.714285714286, 175.825737265416, 257.021621621622, 
162.417582417582, 140.558752997602, 269.202156334232, 205.930666666667, 
242.968), var4 = c(11.8447368421053, 161.75204359673, 477.601092896175, 
32.008174386921, 195.765498652291, 123.914438502674, 2.54918032786885, 
4624.49333333333, 530.69465648855, 363.416216216216, 141.614361702128, 
158.641873278237, 71.0026954177898, 146.747311827957, 5842.73456790123, 
1985.6222826087, 4728.29427792916, 28.2768817204301, 8.42587601078167, 
200.327956989247, 28.5576407506702, 30.1117021276596, 26.6943699731903, 
415.878706199461, 50.6130790190736, 102.155737704918, 76.6436170212766, 
54.3387096774194, 15.5068119891008, 94.3224932249322, 616.588235294118, 
18.1010928961749, 19.5603217158177, 530.32970027248, 2797.23545706371, 
7.68956043956044, 23.5518867924528, 41.078167115903, 106.367021276596, 
185.471849865952, 50.5292553191489, 598.656756756757, 397.997630331754, 
895.881266490765, 252.637426900585, 20.4946524064171, 40.632, 
11.0949868073879, 425.351498637602, 969.255494505495, 392.557692307692, 
1097.05614973262, 307.346994535519, 62.2520325203252, 606.558510638298, 
168.951482479784, 258.60433604336, 18.1758241758242, 447.486559139785, 
72.8208556149733, 221.960106382979, 69.1689008042895, 13.1825613079019, 
28.9784946236559, 176.195054945055, 102.30563002681, 1223.25382262997, 
65.7704485488127, 465.583783783784, 1.02139037433155, 335.677595628415, 
510.538461538462, 195.667560321716, 241.634615384615, 385.98904109589, 
534.534246575342, 78.9378378378378, 57.2886904761905, 12.3722826086957, 
34.425068119891, 204.577656675749, 30.6853333333333, 190.997340425532, 
49.5877659574468, 208.926229508197, 415.878706199461, 129.612903225806, 
99.6021505376344, 31.8509485094851, 25.1737089201878, 35.9460916442048, 
38.1226666666667, 19.9125683060109, 418.600536193029, 52.8369565217391, 
294.002732240437, 34.7074340527578, 1561.25201072386, 116.048387096774, 
47.5645161290323), var5 = c("A", "B", "E", "E", "C", "B", 
"A", "D", "D", "A", "C", "C", "D", "A", "E", "D", "E", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "D", "B", "E", "A", "E", "C", "A", "C", 
"D", "C", "B", "E", "C", "B", "A", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"D", "E", "B", "D", "B", "C", "C", "E", "A", "E", "A", "D", 
"C", "B", "A", "A", "D", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", 
"E", "B", "D", "C", "C", "E", "A", "B", "E", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "D", "A", "B", "E", "B", "C", "B", "A", "E", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "E", "A", "E", "C", "E", "C", "B"), deforestation = c(0, 
0.00088273700705145, 0.00121441629668321, 0.0138338991903891, 
0.000770436145207626, 0, 0, 0.0159336641420736, 0.00361190911465134, 
0.00488639331418125, 0, 0, 0.00427526769391486, 1.04465917994254e-05, 
0, 0.0150352572473231, 0.0112535910159311, 0, 5.48446069469835e-05, 
0, 8.09610864455471e-05, 0.000934969966048577, 0.000292504570383912, 
0.000613737268216245, 0.00330112300861844, 0.0009036301906503, 
0, 0.000274223034734918, 0.0288169234787151, 0.00360929746670149, 
0, 0, 0.00474797597283886, 0.000856620527552886, 0.00404283102637764, 
0.0136171324105511, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000605902324366675, 
1.82815356489945e-05, 0.00171324105510577, 0.0198119613476103, 
0, 0.000634630451815095, 0.0169939932097153, 0.016617915904936, 
0.000519717942021416, 0.000577174196918255, 0, 0, 0.000182815356489945, 
0, 0.000101854270044398, 0.00011491250979368, 0.00586314964742753, 
0.000321232697832332, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00360146252285192, 0.00218594933402977, 
0.0127135022199008, 0.00441368503525725, 0, 0.000282057978584487, 
0.000407417080177592, 7.31261425959781e-05, 0.00212849307913293, 
8.35727343954035e-05, 0.00435884042831026, 0.000146252285191956, 
0.000746931313658919, 0.00730216766779838, 0, 0.0183990598067381, 
0.0321441629668321, 0.000694698354661792, 0, 0.00102376599634369, 
0, 0, 0.000613737268216245, 0.00142073648472186, 1.04465917994254e-05, 
0.0105693392530687, 0, 0.000770436145207626, 0.00127187255158005, 
0.0246983546617916, 0.0107312614259598, 0.0182031862104988, 
0.00117524157743536, 2.35048315487072e-05, 0, 0, 0.0237973361190911
), var6 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), var7 = c(45, 
33, 40, 40, 26, 43, 28, 30, 65, 36, 71, 28, 43, 30, 45, 60, 
50, 44, 30, 28, 70, 38, 34, 45, 35, 71, 30, 35, 26, 35, 20, 
35, 33, 28, 24, 40, 60, 31, 60, 26, 40, 26, 59, 65, 28, 43, 
25, 27, 42, 37, 34, 38, 24, 29, 36, 52, 35, 33, 35, 35, 22, 
63, 35, 25, 26, 39, 61, 28, 50, 26, 27, 25, 30, 30, 29, 26, 
64, 40, 41, 37, 32, 48, 24, 30, 40, 38, 49, 29, 24, 60, 32, 
58, 47, 74, 33, 34, 36, 35, 45, 50), var8 = c(9L, 2L, 3L, 
10L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 16L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 
6L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 6L), var9 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("V1", "V2"
), class = "factor"), var10 = c("A", "C", "D", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", 
"D", "A", "B", "B", "B", "D", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", 
"A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "B", "A"), response = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), response_offset = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Region = structure(c(62L, 
54L, 15L, 48L, 16L, 67L, 27L, 49L, 53L, 20L, 21L, 18L, 10L, 
67L, 5L, 60L, 49L, 52L, 32L, 38L, 9L, 7L, 56L, 33L, 50L, 
22L, 62L, 2L, 59L, 9L, 65L, 26L, 55L, 14L, 28L, 57L, 43L, 
1L, 3L, 63L, 70L, 14L, 39L, 58L, 74L, 52L, 6L, 58L, 74L, 
36L, 24L, 64L, 35L, 12L, 65L, 19L, 13L, 57L, 17L, 62L, 51L, 
41L, 34L, 66L, 16L, 44L, 61L, 21L, 20L, 47L, 29L, 53L, 68L, 
31L, 23L, 15L, 22L, 8L, 46L, 57L, 36L, 21L, 73L, 37L, 27L, 
33L, 72L, 71L, 45L, 42L, 4L, 11L, 57L, 69L, 45L, 25L, 40L, 
30L, 64L, 45L), .Label = c("REG102", "REG107", "REG11", "REG111", 
"REG113", "REG115", "REG118", "REG12", "REG121", "REG123", 
"REG126", "REG127", "REG129", "REG131", "REG132", "REG135", 
"REG137", "REG139", "REG140", "REG147", "REG15", "REG152", 
"REG153", "REG158", "REG161", "REG167", "REG169", "REG174", 
"REG179", "REG18", "REG182", "REG187", "REG189", "REG191", 
"REG196", "REG197", "REG2", "REG200", "REG203", "REG205", 
"REG21", "REG220", "REG221", "REG230", "REG240", "REG242", 
"REG29", "REG30", "REG31", "REG33", "REG35", "REG4", "REG45", 
"REG47", "REG49", "REG51", "REG53", "REG59", "REG64", "REG65", 
"REG68", "REG70", "REG73", "REG77", "REG82", "REG84", "REG85", 
"REG88", "REG89", "REG9", "REG91", "REG93", "REG95", "REG96"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("community_ID", "var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "deforestation", "var6", "var7", 
"var8", "var9", "var10", "response", "response_offset", "Region"
), row.names = c(96822L, 37621L, 198447L, 38614L, 189867L, 94096L, 
172690L, 38339L, 24948L, 156137L, 1191L, 161233L, 133628L, 80703L, 
135780L, 49773L, 45072L, 4447L, 186638L, 179435L, 139007L, 138519L, 
51329L, 180382L, 32818L, 169577L, 88229L, 106915L, 72504L, 136765L, 
80539L, 152058L, 69038L, 155271L, 168337L, 70323L, 215515L, 120369L, 
14622L, 97858L, 2920L, 157591L, 211175L, 58830L, 129946L, 21754L, 
133166L, 56436L, 109732L, 188847L, 152541L, 90464L, 185546L, 
188145L, 79329L, 162503L, 147197L, 66379L, 154617L, 78220L, 30719L, 
7163L, 170249L, 96917L, 190072L, 237192L, 69165L, 2734L, 196101L, 
37984L, 192173L, 31960L, 75791L, 193273L, 166014L, 198148L, 160416L, 
17150L, 239018L, 70854L, 189105L, 14954L, 106963L, 14003L, 154347L, 
180388L, 104110L, 83342L, 230565L, 206489L, 138766L, 134485L, 
67206L, 73819L, 235106L, 191261L, 204568L, 11998L, 82142L, 233744L
), class = "data.frame")
```